# mysql like and different value not working

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a form of research every things work fine except the clause `<>` i don't know why happen. any help?

this is my query

```
SELECT users . * , image_upload.name_image
FROM users
LEFT JOIN image_upload ON users.profile_image = image_upload.id_image
WHERE users.id <>1
AND LOWER( users.name ) LIKE  'f%'
OR LOWER( users.surname ) LIKE  'f%'
LIMIT 5
```

when start the query, it shows the row with the id = 1 logically is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT users . * , image_upload.name_image
FROM users
LEFT JOIN image_upload ON users.profile_image = image_upload.id_image
WHERE users.id <>1
AND (LOWER( users.name ) LIKE  'f%'
OR LOWER( users.surname ) LIKE  'f%')
LIMIT 5
```

Remember that the OR statement really has to be in parenthesis due to the way that operators are processed.

Here's a link for you:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: Ok, Perfect! Thank you so much! Now i understood the reason. Cheese.